# Android: How to stop a play list in media player

Tags: android, media-player, avaudioplayer

I am Unable to stop a running playlist.It gives error of native method.Play List stopped while using **Async class**. Please check my `fragment` and **PlayMedia Class.**

```
public static  int[] playList= {
              R.raw.song1, R.raw.song2,
              R.raw.song3, R.raw.song4
      };

    @OnClick(R.id.tablaPlayControl_mImageView)
        public void playTablaSounds() {
            if (!tablaPlay) {
                tablaPlayControl_mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                tablaPlay = true;
                playAudio = new PlayMedia(getContext(), playList);
                playAudio.execute();

           } else {

               tablaPlayControl_mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
               playAudio.onCancelled();
               playAudio.execute();
                tablaPlay = false;

           }
        }
```

Method in Async claas **PlayMedia.class** to stop play list

```
  @Override
        public void onCancelled() {
             super.onCancelled();
            Log.e("Log 1", "" + mediaPlayer);
            if (  mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
```

Here is my `logcat` where its crashes. Please check.

```
   app.android.atabla E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ain
   Process: app.android.atabla, PID: 23104 java.lang.IllegalStateException
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
   at app.android.atabla.CommonUtils.Utils.PlayMedia.onCancelled(PlayMedia.java:91)
```